# Flutter: Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method on channel)

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter

I would like to call a kotlin function inside my flutter code (just to set parameters using the consent sdk), however, every time I try to call the function (currently just test code) I get the error:
`Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getConsent on channel consent.sdk/consent)`

This is how my `MainActivity.kt` looks like:

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
    MethodChannel(flutterView, "consent.sdk/consent").setMethodCallHandler {
      // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
      call, result ->
      if (call.method == "getConsent") {
        result.success("Yay")
      } else {
        result.success("Yey")
        //result.notImplemented() Commented out to see if this caused the error, but it didn't
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is how I try to "run" this code in flutter:

```
const platform = const MethodChannel('consent.sdk/consent');
Future<String> _getConsent() async {
  String result;
  try {
    result = await platform.invokeMethod('getConsent');
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    result = "Failed: '${e.message}'.";
  }
  return result;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you failed to rebuild the app after you added the Native code, after changing the MainActivity.kt you must rebuild your project only then the native codes will work. If you did get the same error after rebuilding, do try Clean and rebuild.

If non of these work, do post your flutter doctor -v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So my problem was fixed by running:
`flutter clean` and then running the application

Thanks [dlohani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3234890/dlohani)